# Contador regressivo

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web

Boa tarde,
Quero acrescentar na minha página um contador regressivo, que no final so emita um aviso dizendo que o tempo expirou.

É possivel fazer isso com html?
estou sem  idéia.

Comment: javascript e php poderiam fazer isso juntamente com o html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var configMinuto;
    var configSegundo;
    var mostrarValor;
    var evento = null;
    var contador = null;
    var minuto = 0;
    var segundo = 0;

    function IniciarCronometro(valor){
     this.evento = valor;
     this.configMinuto = document.getElementById('min').value;
     this.configSegundo = document.getElementById('seg').value;
     this.mostrarValor = document.getElementById('mostrarValor');
     
     
     if (evento=="start"){
      if(!document.getElementById('min').readOnly){
       if(!this.validarNumero(this.configMinuto)){
        alert("Campo minuto não é um número!");
        return;
       }
       if(!this.validarNumero(this.configSegundo) || document.getElementById('seg').value > 59){
        alert("Campo segundo não é um número válido (0 a 59)!");
        return;
       }
       
       document.getElementById('min').readOnly = true;
       document.getElementById('seg').readOnly = true;
       this.minuto = document.getElementById('min').value;
       this.segundo = document.getElementById('seg').value;
       
       document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.remove('mostrarValor');
       document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.add('mostrarValor2');
       document.getElementById('exibe').classList.remove('Classexibe');
       document.getElementById('exibe').classList.add('Classexibe2');
       
      }else{
       if(this.segundo == 0 && this.minuto != 0){
        this.segundo = 59;
        this.minuto--;
       }else{
        this.segundo--;
       }
       if(this.minuto == 0 && this.segundo == 0){
        document.getElementById('min').readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById('seg').readOnly = false;
        this.mostrarValor.value = "03:00";
        
        document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.remove('mostrarValor2');
        document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.add('mostrarValor');
        document.getElementById('exibe').classList.remove('Classexibe2');
        document.getElementById('exibe').classList.add('Classexibe');
       
        clearTimeout(this.contador);
        return;
       } 
       
       novoMinuto = null;
       novoSegundo = null;
       if(this.minuto <= 9){
        novoMinuto = "0" + this.minuto;
       }else{
        novoMinuto = this.minuto;
       }
       if(this.segundo <= 9){
        novoSegundo = "0" + this.segundo;
       }else{
        novoSegundo = this.segundo;
       }
       this.mostrarValor.value = novoMinuto + ":" + novoSegundo;
      }
     }
     clearTimeout(this.contador);
     this.contador = setTimeout('IniciarCronometro(evento)', 1000);
    }

    function validarNumero(valor){
     return !isNaN(parseFloat(valor)) && isFinite(valor);
    }
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 99%;
}
body {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.mostrarValor{
 text-align: center;
 border:0px solid white;
 font-size: 50pt;
}
.mostrarValor2{
 text-align: center;
 border:0px solid white;
 font-size: 50pt;
 animation: fade 10000ms infinite;
}

.Classexibe, .Classexibe2{
 text-align:center;
}

section {
 width: 450px;
}

.btn {
 
 width:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>CRONÔMETRO</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <section>
   <fieldset class="Classexibe" id="exibe">
    <p><input class="mostrarValor" type="text" id="mostrarValor" size="2" readonly="readonly" value="03:00"/></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="min" size="2" maxlength="3" value='3'/>
    <input type="hidden" id="seg" size="2" maxlength="2" value='0' />
           <input class="btn" type="button" value="INICIAR" id="btnIniciar" onclick="IniciarCronometro('start')"> 
   </fieldset>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Só uma duvida...o primeiro bloco começa direto assim "var configMinuto;"?

Comment: era desta forma ?, Bom o primeiro bloco vem dentro de uma tag <script> e quando o código acabar feche a tag script. o segundo código necessita ser salvo em arquivo com extensão .CSS pois é um estilo, e o terceiro é um arquivo HTML. E sim, começa ali em var configMinuto.

Comment: No caso eu so preciso msm do contador em si, mas eu tento tirar esses campos Minutos e Segundos

Comment: @olifreitas vai ser necessário pegar o que está dentro do body pelo menos, para você ter o código com eficiência

Comment: Sem querer abusar, vc saberia me dizer no momento que pagina é aberta o cronometro ja começa a rodar?

Comment: @olifreitas Você tera que colocar o id e o evento onClick no botão de logar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68398/discussion-between-victor-and-olifreitas).

Comment: <section>
    <article>
      <fieldset class="Classexibe" id="exibe"><legend></legend>
        <p><input class="mostrarValor" type="text" id="onClick" size="2" readonly="readonly" value="03:00"/></p>
     
    </article>
  </section>
assim?

Comment: copie a tag <section> e tudo que esta dentro dela eu editei o código deixando bem simples agora , lembrando que ... deve copiar até o </section>

Comment: Muito obrigado! mas o eu tentei dizer foi que no momento que  pagina é carregada o cronometro ja começa a rodar, sem precisar de clicar num botao iniciar.

Comment: então e eu respondi, para isso acontecer você deve copiar o ID e o evento onclick do botão iniciar e colocar em algum botão, seja no botão logar ou pode ser também em algum link